# Use the same function to validate 2 different questions

Tags: c

I'm having an issue with trying to figure out how to use the same function (validate), to validate 2 different number inputs, using 2 different questions

```
int validate(int low, int high) {
    int flag = 0, number = 0;

    do 
    {
        printf("Enter maximum value between %d and %d: ", low, high);
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if (number <= low || number > high) 
        {
            printf("INVALID! Must enter a value between %d and %d: ", low, high);
            scanf("%d", &number);
        }
        else {
            flag = 1;
        }
    } while(flag == 0);
    return number;
}
```

Here is main()

```
int main () {
    int num1, num2;

    switch(menu()) {
    case 1:
    printf("~~~~~~~\n6/49 Number Generator\n");
    num1 = validate(1,49);
    num2 = validate(1, 6);
    break;
    default:
        printf("end");
    }
return(0);
}
```

When I call `validate()` the second time (returning `num2`), I need it to ask for a quantity of numbers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your function is both doing input and validation (not validation alone).  Your input code should check that `scanf()` is successful; you have to decide what to do if it is not.  It isn't obvious why you are using asymmetric tests (`if (number <= low || number > high)`); using `<` would probably be more normal.  It is not clear what you mean by "I need to ask it for a quantity of numbers".  If you mean you need it to collect an array full of numbers, you need a second function that handles an array full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your validate() should have another parameter signifying what it's gonna actually do.
Something like `int validate(int low, int high, int type)`.

Then switch on type to do the various operations. But then I'd advise you to change the name of the function as validate would not be too appropriate. e.g. `numGenEngine` where type would signify step1, step2 etc.

Considering you need the function definition intact, you can use static variable.

```
int validate(int low, int high) {
    static int step = 0;
    int flag = 0, number = 0;

    if (step == 0) {
        // the first thing
    } else if (step == 1) {
        // the other thing
            // to reuse the function for the next set of operations
            // reset step to -1 here
    }

    step++;
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are restricted to this function signature you can use internal static flag